# Using Windows Server Backup to schedule a folder backup

Tags: windows, backup

Is there a way to schedule a backup using Windows Server backup to use a folder only on a separate drive as its backup location?

Here's a scenario :

```
Folder to backup : C:\temp\files\
Schedule : Every day, 8:00PM
Destination : E:\backup\files\ only
```

I am quite confuse as the destination type on the app, as I understand, will erase the content of the location. So I am hesitant to use Drive E: as it seems that it will clear all of its contents.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not clear its contents. Usually Windows Server Backup saves it's backups in a separate folder **WindowsImageBackup** that is created in the root of the specified disk.

However if you want to backup to a certain folder you can make your desired backup folder to a shared folder and perform a Windows Server Backup to a shared folder instead of disk.

1. On the **Specify Destination Type** page, select **Back up to a shared network folder**.
2. On the **Specify Remote Shared Folder** page, type the path to the folder. In this folder, a folder named **WindowsImageBackup** will be created. The backup that you create will be saved at: \\\WindowsImageBackup\.

Full information on how to do it can be found here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851825(v=ws.11).aspx